Page Load Time GA4 and GTM
page load time in GMT correctly but in Google Analytics I can't Show page load time
I Get Page Load Time in debug view [object object].
i try to add Page load time in GA4 page load time is show in GTM but not show in GA4.

That's because you send a javascript object to that parameter. You can add more detail or screenshot about how you set it. What you see in preview mode and debug mode.
